# how to assign a value to one column by checking the condition on different columns using where,select, loc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, select, where-clause

assign values to a column based on multiple columns in dataframe

I have a following code - where I am trying assign value to a column based age of the person

```
conditions = [df['age']<=25,df['age']>25,df['age']>=50]
values = ['age below 25','between 25 and 50','50+']
df['age category']=np.select(conditions,values)
```

output -

```
gender  name    age age category
0   male    A   45  between 25 and 50
1   female  B   22  age below 25
2   other   C   54  between 25 and 50
```

for the age 54 it should assign age category as 50+

so i have tried following code which shows a error

```
conditions = [df['age']<=25,(df['age']>25 & df['age']<50),df['age']>=50]
values = ['age below 25','between 25 and 50','50+']
df['age category']=np.select(conditions,values)
```

I think we can use either where, select or loc for this but entirely not sure.. Thanks in advance

Comment: What error it throws?

Comment: \Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1536     def __nonzero__(self):
   1537         raise ValueError(
-> 1538             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1539             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
   1540         )

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: I found the solution we just need to used apply function and we have to pass the function within in apply - df['cage']=df['age'].apply(a)
def a(x):
    if x<=25:
        return 'age below 25'
    elif x>50: 
        return '50+'
    elif x>25 & x<=50:
        return 'between 25 and 50'

Comment: Your `truth value error` is because you didn't enclose the expression with parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) here:

```
### user defined threshold ages in order
ages = [25, 50]

### below is programmatic
labels = ([f'age below {ages[0]}']
          +[f'between {a} and {b}'
            for a,b in zip(ages, ages[1:])]
          +[f'{ages[-1]}+']
         )

df['age category'] = pd.cut(df['age'], bins=[0]+ages+[np.inf], labels=labels)
```

Output:

```
   gender name  age       age category
0    male    A   45  between 25 and 50
1  female    B   22       age below 25
2   other    C   54                50+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `default` parameter for `np.select` and since the first condition encountered is selected, you can use:

```
conditions = [df['age'] < 25, df['age'] < 50]
values = ['age below 25', 'between 25 and 50']
df['age category'] = np.select(conditions, values, default='50+')
print(df)

# Output:
    age       age category
0    56                50+
1    18       age below 25
2    39  between 25 and 50
3    21       age below 25
4    13       age below 25
5    24       age below 25
6    54                50+
7    47  between 25 and 50
8    43  between 25 and 50
9    60                50+
10   65                50+
11   21       age below 25
12   53                50+
13   66                50+
14   52                50+
15   13       age below 25
16   10       age below 25
17   46  between 25 and 50
18   13       age below 25
19   57                50+
```